# Update Vuetify version

Tags: npm, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

To update the Vuetify component library in my project, I changed the version in `package.json` and ran the command `npm install`. Vuetify is now removed from the `node_modules` folder. How should I install it again? Why does `npm install Vuetify` not bring it back into `node_modules`?

Comment: try `npm -S i vuetify`. does that bring it back?

Comment: no, nothing happend @Traxo

Comment: Do you get any errors after running the command? try deleting `node_modules`, run `npm cache clean`, and then `npm i`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Run `npm info vuetify` to lookup for the list of versions that they have.

Install the specific version that you want with the following. I am using the latest `vuetify v1.0.0-beta.6` as an example.

Example:

```
npm install --save vuetify@1.0.0-beta.6
```

Alternatively, if you prefer `yarn`

```
yarn add vuetify@1.0.0-beta.6
```

You can replace `--save` with `-S` flag instead.

`yarn` requires no flags to save them into `dependencies`.

Comment: okey, it appends applied version to package.json. But why there is not any folder named vuetify in node_module directory?

Comment: It is working for me `drwxr-xr-x  11 username  staff     352 Feb  8 19:43 vuetify
`

Answer (score 13):

to update vuetify version you must uninstall your old vuetify here is what i mean

uninstall it first

```
npm uninstall -S vuetify
```

then install it again

```
npm install -S vuetify
```

if you want to specify the version

```
npm install -S vuetify@1.0.0
```

for example.

`-S` or `--save` is for `dependencies`

Comment: Please have a look at the existing answer. It's working and even solving OP's issue.

Comment: i was explaining the how to install the specific version, current version and to uninstall

Comment: But that is not what OP asked for. OP simply wants to update and this issue has been solved by the accepted answer above.

Comment: I have tried this method but there is an error, https://i.ibb.co/59s4s2D/stylus.png

Comment: @MohamadHandyNugraha what vuetify version you`re installing

Answer (score 8):

Since *npm* version 5 (part of *Node.js* version 8), you can simply run

```
npm update vuetify
```

to update the package in `node_modules` and version in `package.json`/`package.json.lock` to the latest *wanted* version. Wanted version is the latest safe version that can be selected according to the constraints of semantic versioning and the `^` or `~` prefix in `package.json`.

To see what is the available wanted version, run

```
npm outdated
```

If you want to update both Vuetify and other packages to the latest *major* version (you rarely want this as Vuetify major versions are not necessarily backwards-compatible), run

```
npx npm-check-updates -u
npm install
```

See [this excellent article by Carl Rippon for details](https://www.carlrippon.com/upgrading-npm-dependencies/).

Answer (score -1):

**In Mac or Ubuntu:**

Just try the command `npm install vuetify --save`. It will update with latest one.