# How to upgrade from Vuetify 1.5 to 2.0

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use the vuetify@2.0.0-alpha.17 rather than the 1.5.13 that it automatically starts with when I use vue add Vuetify. then I try this post [Update Vuetify version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684083/update-vuetify-version) method. I do

```
vue create my-app
cd my-app
vue add Vuetify 
npm uninstall -S vuetify 
npm install -S vuetify@2.0.0-alpha.17
```

and just get error

```
This dependency was not found:

* vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl in ./src/plugins/vuetify.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl
```

oh ok that's how install it. no that just gives an error too. Like I just want to start working with 2.0.0 so that when they release it- hopefully soon- I don't have to rebuild everything. Not sure why it's so hard like tell us in the docs how to do it not everybody is a wizard and googling the problem doesn't work

Comment: It's an alpha version, thus still has bugs and they are fixing them (in this case removing stylus bloat, because migrating to sass). https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/6879 PR was not approved, so I presume if they knew 100% how to deal with the issue, they would approve it or at least inform you about how to do it. On the bright side, beta should arrive in may as far as I know, and installation should be easy.

Comment: Ok so this is the correct way. The thing is I've had the 2.0.0 something installed in the past and it worked. ya idk alpha10 seams to work kind of but then the website just shows blank. Guess ill just sit on my hands for a month and plan unless something gets fixed in meantime

Comment: if you figure anything out on this please post...
I am trying to upgrade for some of the new datatable features and running into the same exact error!!

Comment: For vuetify 2.0 beta see this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/56368052/6385184

Answer (score 14):

Comment out `import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'` in your `src/plugins/vuetify.js` file.
add `import 'vuetify/src/styles/main.sass'`
then `npm install sass-loader`

Answer (score 1):

Vuetify v2 does not use the stylus. Remove import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl' from src/plugins/vuetify.js. Or downgrade your vuetify plugin to 1.5.x (not recomended).