# How to install vuetify 2.0 beta to the new vue cli project?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

Vuetify 2.0.0-beta.0 has just been released and I want to try it out and play around in a new vue test application.
But I get errors when I try to install it in a fresh new project. Here are the steps I've taken.

I use `@vue/cli v3.8.2` to create a new project with default settings:

```
vue create testapp
```

which gives me successful result:

```
  Successfully created project testapp.
  Get started with the following commands:

 $ cd testapp
 $ npm run serve
```

Then I add vuetify plugin to the project with default (recommended) preset:

```
cd testapp
vue add vuetify
```

which gives me success:

```
  Installing vue-cli-plugin-vuetify...

+ vue-cli-plugin-vuetify@0.5.0
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 23942 packages in 9.235s
found 0 vulnerabilities

✔  Successfully installed plugin: vue-cli-plugin-vuetify

? Choose a preset: Default (recommended)

  Invoking generator for vue-cli-plugin-vuetify...
  Installing additional dependencies...

added 11 packages from 49 contributors and audited 23980 packages in 9.252s
found 0 vulnerabilities

⚓  Running completion hooks...

✔  Successfully invoked generator for plugin: vue-cli-plugin-vuetify
```

Now in `package.json` I see vuetify version:
`"vuetify": "^1.5.5"`

I now update it to the `v2.0.0-beta.0` like this:

```
npm install vuetify@2.0.0-beta.0
```

I get success again:

```
+ vuetify@2.0.0-beta.0
updated 1 package and audited 23980 packages in 10.302s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Now when I try to run it:

```
npm run serve
```

I get error:

```
> testapp@0.1.0 serve c:\temp\testapp
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
 98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 99 errors                                                                                                                                                                                           6:17:04 PM

This dependency was not found:

* vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl in ./src/plugins/vuetify.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl
Failed to resolve loader: sass-loader
You may need to install it.
```

If I install sass-loader like this:

```
npm i -D node-sass sass-loader
```

I get success. Then I try to run it again:

```
npm run serve
```

Now again I get different error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                                            6:27:06 PM

This dependency was not found:

* vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl in ./src/plugins/vuetify.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl
```

I am stuck here as I don't know how to fix this error. `npm install --save vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl` obviously don't work. Also I couldn't make it work neither by following official [vuetify page](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#full-install) for this beta release.

Comment: 2.0.0 has now been released. Installation and upgrade instructions here: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/v2.0.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After creating a new fresh vue project follow those commands:

```
# yarn
$ yarn add https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vue-cli-plugin-vuetify.git#dev -D
$ vue invoke vuetify

# npm
$ npm install https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vue-cli-plugin-vuetify.git#dev --save-dev
$ vue invoke vuetify
```

I think it will even work with the project you have already created. Just try the commands above.

For more check [v2.0.0-beta.0 release](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/v2.0.0-beta.0)

Comment: this should be the right answer, as this works for beta.2 without any extra hassle... should be in docs also :)

Answer (score 11):

Don't include .styl files, it's deprecated basically.
Remove `node-sass` and install `sass`

```sh
$ npm uninstall node-sass
$ npm i -D sass
```

And modify your `plugins/vuetify.js` file

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'


Vue.use(Vuetify)
export default new Vuetify({ theme: { ... } })
```

And `main.js`

```js
new Vue({
  ...
  vuetify, // we add vuetify here
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Note theme options changed in v2, dark theme can now be customized, e.g.

```js
theme: {
  dark: true,
  themes: {
    light: {
      primary: '#42a5f5',
      //...
    },
    dark: {
      primary: '#2196F3.
    },
  },
},
options: {
  customProperties: true,
},
icons: {
  iconfont: 'md', // default is 'mdi'
}
```

More in [docs](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start), and [new style docs](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/theme#modifying-sass-variables) with regards to sass.

Comment: how can I use yarn to remove node-sass and add sass and sass-loader?

Comment: @KickButtowski try `yarn remove node-sass`, and `yarn add sass`