# How do I install next vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to install the newest release of vuetify (2.0.0-beta.0)
I have a project made with Vue Cli 3.7.0 and with Vuetify 1.5.X
I've tried some ways to install it, and I wasn't successful.

What am I doing wrong?

Steps that I've followed:

- Update vuetify: `npm install -S vuetify@2.0.0-beta.0`
- Install sass: `npm i -D sass`
- Delete `styl imports` in vuetify.js
- Add `export default new Vuetify()` in vuetify.js
- In main.js

```
add new Vue({
  ...
  vuetify, // <- this
  ...
})
```

When I run the code, the error I get is:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in getter for watcher "isDark": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dark' of undefined"

found in

---> <VApp>
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

I'm not using "dark" property, and the problem is in the App.vue, where I only have a component and anything else, I don't have vuetify code there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install vuetify 2.0 beta to the new vue cli project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56364965/how-to-install-vuetify-2-0-beta-to-the-new-vue-cli-project)

Comment: similar error - https://stackoverflow.com/q/57019082/6921475