# Setting up new Vuetfy 2 Beta 7 - Error in getter for watcher "isDark"

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using 2.0.0-beta.7 version of vuetify on a newly setup Vue project. I am getting below errors

```
Error in getter for watcher "isDark": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dark' of undefined"
```

also,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dark' of undefined
```

### plugins/vuetify.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

const opts = {
  icon: {
    iconfont: 'fa',
  }
};
Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify(opts);
```

### main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  Vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Below links helped in identifying that there is some issue in my setup.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56367842/4050261
- https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta.0
- https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```js
> new Vue({
>   router,
>   store,
>   Vuetify,
>   render: h => h(App)
> })
> ```

It has to be lowercase here:

```js
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```