# How to create a vuetify superset to extend basic functionality

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frameworks, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a plugin based component library to provide consistency across multiple product lines using vuetify. However, install the library and add the components, I get several errors regarding dark theme.

Both the component library and the target product line have vuetify installed via the vue-cli.

```
<template>
     <div class="module-wrap">
        <v-card v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners" :class="`dashboard-module units`">
            <v-toolbar flat dense :color="color">
                <v-toolbar-title>{{title}}</v-toolbar-title>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-menu v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners"  class="menu" offset-y>
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                        <v-btn class="menu-opener" icon v-on="on">
                            <font-awesome-icon icon="ellipsis-h"></font-awesome-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                    </template>
                    <v-list>
                        <v-list-tile class="tooltip" @click="dialog = true">
                            <v-list-tile-avatar>
                                <font-awesome-icon icon="info"/>
                            </v-list-tile-avatar>
                            <v-list-tile-content>
                                <v-list-tile-title>Information</v-list-tile-title>
                            </v-list-tile-content>
                        </v-list-tile>
                        <v-list-tile class="favorite" @click="$emit('favorite')">
                            <v-list-tile-avatar>
                                <font-awesome-icon icon="star"/>
                            </v-list-tile-avatar>
                            <v-list-tile-content>
                                <v-list-tile-title>Save To Favorites</v-list-tile-title>
                            </v-list-tile-content>
                        </v-list-tile>
                        <v-list-tile class="export" v-if="!disableExport" @click="$emit('export')">
                            <v-list-tile-avatar>
                                <font-awesome-icon icon="file-export"/> 
                            </v-list-tile-avatar>
                            <v-list-tile-content>
                                <v-list-tile-title>Export</v-list-tile-title>
                            </v-list-tile-content>
                        </v-list-tile>
                    </v-list>
                </v-menu>
            </v-toolbar>
            <div :class="`content`">
                <slot></slot>
            </div>
            <v-card-text>
                <slot name="card-text"></slot>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="500">
                <v-card>
                    <v-card-title>
                        <div class="headline">{{title}}</div>
                    </v-card-title>
                    <v-card-text>
                        <slot name="tooltip"></slot>
                    </v-card-text>
                    
                    <v-card-actions>
                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                        <v-btn @click="dialog = false" flat color="primary">Ok</v-btn>
                    </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
            </v-dialog>
        </v-card>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

export default {
    // props:['color', 'module', 'title'],
    props: {
        color:String,
        title:String,
        disableExport:Boolean
    },
    
    data() {
        return {
            dialog:false
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

.dashboard-module {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}
.content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height: 100%;
}

</style>
```

^ Component from library

```
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/dashboard-components/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:620 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dark' of undefined"

found in

---> <VMenu>
       <TDashboardModule>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'dark' of undefined`

```
[Vue warn]: Error in getter for watcher "isDark": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dark' of undefined"

found in

---> <ThemeProvider>
       <VDialog>
         <TDashboardModule>
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
```

^ Errors thrown

vuetify Version 1.5.14

Comment: it seems to be vuetify v2 error? Please specify your vuetify version. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56367842/1981247 on how to properly migrate from vue-cli install because it currently installs v1, then you add v2 manually.

Comment: I'm using Version 1.5.14 in both projects, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup the theme color? And where? In case negative, in accordance to the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/theme):

> Vuetify supports both light and dark variants of the Material Design
>   spec. This designation starts at the root application component, v-app
>   and is supported by majority of components. By default, your
>   application will use the light theme, but this can be easily
>   overwritten by adding the dark prop.

```
<v-app dark>
```

If you don't want to setup everything in one color, you can pass for example a prop named dark to the components in order to make them use the dark theme:

```
<v-menu dark>
```

[Documentation about menu component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus#menu)

Comment: Yes the component is being wrapped in the ```<v-app>``` tag and there are no changes to the theming itself.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand, did you apply the 'dark' prop to the v-app as I mentioned? or to the components?

Comment: The v-app itself