# trouble migrating to vuetify 2.0 beta (.5)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I followed the guide here: 
https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start, initially I had set it up with tree shaking but seeing the warning that tree shaking only works with webpack 4 in production mode, I installed the vuetify loader, this did not solve the issue. 
Here is my setup:

```
//src/plugins/vuetify.js:
import Vue from 'vue'

import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

import {MdIcons} from "../assets/icons/mdIcons";
//import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'
import '../assets/stylus/main.styl'
const opts = {
    theme: {
        dark: true,
        themes: {
            light: {
                primary: '#4169E1',
                white: '#ffffff',
                accent: '#111',
                error: '#b71c1c',
                warning: '#DF9627',
                grayf1: '#F8F8F9',
                grayDE: '#EDEDEE',
                grayCE: '#969696',
                avatar: '#FC6A70',
                green: '#69B769'
            },
            dark: {
                primary: '#4169E1',
                white: '#ffffff',
                accent: '#111',
                error: '#b71c1c',
                warning: '#DF9627',
                grayf1: '#F8F8F9',
                grayDE: '#EDEDEE',
                grayCE: '#969696',
                avatar: '#FC6A70',
                green: '#69B769'
            }
        }

    },
    options: {
        themeVariations: ['primary', 'accent', 'white'],
        customProperties: true
    },
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'mdi', // default
        values: MdIcons
    }
}
Vue.use(Vuetify);
export default new Vuetify(opts)

//main.js:

import Vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
...
new Vue({
                router,
                store,
                i18n,
                Vuetify,
                render: h => h(App),
...
```

NONE of my components load the page looks like its from 1992, here is a sample error of what I am getting:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:601 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-pagination> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <SearchUsers> at src/components/SearchUsers.vue
       <UsersList> at src/views/UsersList.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

package.json which seems to have the `vuetify-loader` as recommneded, `sass`/`sass-loader`, the latest version of vuetify.

```
{
  "name": "users-manager-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --mode local",
    "build_dev": "vue-cli-service build --mode dev",
    "build_stg": "vue-cli-service build --mode stg",
    "build_prod": "vue-cli-service build --mode prod"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "css-vars-ponyfill": "^1.16.2",
    "deepmerge": "^3.3.0",
    "em-common-vue": "^0.1.0",
    "fibers": "^4.0.1",
    "innersvg-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.21",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.8.0",
    "vue-material-design-icons": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.5.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.22.2",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.0.5"
  }
}
```

EDIT: I installed vuetify loader as instructed in the docs above (with the vue-cli-plugin) in addition I just ran npm install.
Please help!

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56364965/how-to-install-vuetify-2-0-beta-to-the-new-vue-cli-project/56367842#56367842

Comment: @Traxo indeed but unfortunately did not help in my case (the question there is about setting up a new project which I may do if I cannot resolve this)

Comment: Well it seems you had been using a bit older version of vuetify, so you did not have vuetify-loader? Just see how to set it up. Just npm install is not enough for that. Your error seems to indicate that the problem is with `vuetify-loader` setup, so probably search for solutions with that regard then.

Comment: I edited to explain how I installed `vuetify-loader` also it is in my package JSON so I dont understand why it wouldn't work

Comment: Yes, but only means that you have package installed. You did not probably include it in your webpack config. You need to config as per docs https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but how did you install vuetify-loader via the vue-cli-plugin? I was not aware of that installation option. But anyway, if you did not have vuetify-loader prior to your attempt to migrate to v2, then read the vuetify-loader installation docs which I linked to.

Comment: this is a project created with vue-cli I do not have a webpack config (or dont have access to it)

Comment: BTW, you can view your project's webpack config, generated via vue-cli, using this command: `vue inspect > output.js`