# After Upgrading vue I get a white screen of death, [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I upgraded vue and now I get a white screen of death, I'll attach the code

The main error I think I get in the browser is `[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...`

```
// src/main.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify' // path to vuetify export

new Vue({
  vuetify,
}).$mount('#app')
```

// src/plugins/vuetify.js

```
import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css" // Ensure you are using css-loader
import Vue from "vue"
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib"
import {
  transitions,
  VApp,
  VAvatar,
  VBtn,
  VCard,
  VChip,
  VFooter,
  VForm,
  VGrid,
  VIcon,
  VImg,
  VList,
  VNavigationDrawer,
  VParallax,
  VSwitch,
  VTextField,
  VToolbar
} from "vuetify"

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: "mdi" // default - only for display purposes
  },

  components: {
    VApp,
    VAvatar,
    VParallax,
    VNavigationDrawer,
    VFooter,
    VList,
    VCard,
    VBtn,
    VChip,
    VIcon,
    VGrid,
    VToolbar,
    VTextField,
    transitions,
    VForm,
    VImg,
    VSwitch
  },
  theme: {
    primary: "#5fdaee",
    secondary: "#424242",
    accent: "#82B1FF",
    error: "#FF5252",
    info: "#2196F3",
    success: "#4CAF50",
    warning: "#FFC107"
  }
})
```

[image: relevant files]

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^3.8.95",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-analytics": "^5.17.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.7",
    "vuetify": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.9.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-nightwatch": "^3.9.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.9.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.25",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "postcss-custom-properties": "^9.0.2",
    "postcss-nested": "^4.1.2",
    "postcss-smart-import": "^0.7.6",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "sass": "^1.22.7",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.6.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
```

when viewing with devtools all I see is

[image]

Comment: do us a favour and copy the contents of `package.json`

Comment: Upgrading Vuetify from 1.3 to 2.0 seems like a not insignificant detail. The message `[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...` is normal, it doesn't indicate an error. I suggest stopping your server, deleting `node_modules`, re-installing using either `npm` or `yarn` (whichever you normally use), then attempting a clean build. Then try using console logging to see whether your code is running. Inspect the DOM elements of the 'white screen' to see what is actually there. Look through the files in the Network tab. Try introducing a syntax error on purpose to see whether that shows up.

Comment: First of all, you did not properly migrate to vuetify2. See this answer on how to migrate https://stackoverflow.com/a/56367842/1981247  
Then kindly paste any errors here. It seems that your question is misleading because you updated not only vue, but other packages as well (e.g. vuetify)

Comment: sorry I was tied up, will try now

Comment: I was using postcss, maybe that caused some complication.

Comment: @Traxo I have followed those steps, they didn't fix it.

Comment: You could try installing the vue-devtools extension for your browser and see if it recognizes any of the components or the routes.

Comment: @zer0kompression all it sees is root

Comment: As @skirtle mentioned, try triggering an error. Put in some text in the root component (comment out `router-view />` if you have one) and see if the page reflects the text. Comment out any extra CSS and see if that works.

Comment: Looks like I just need to follow the upgrade guide again slowly.

Comment: I made several suggestions for how to investigate this further. To reiterate: 1. Put console logging throughout your code, see what gets hit. 2. Inspect the DOM. 3. Check the files in the Network tab. 4. Deliberately introduce a compilation error to see whether the error message shows up. The clues will be there but it's very difficult to help you if you won't share what you're seeing.

Comment: I just went back to the old version of vuetify, if I need to upgrade I'll just do a fresh install and copy over.