# How to upgrade vuetify 1.4 to vuetify 2.0 version

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to upgrade my current version vuetify 1.4 to 2.0, need help

Comment: But what problems occur? Expand a little your question.

Comment: Strictly read and follow the release notes on GitHub - https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.0.0

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/56364965/1981247

Comment: it will break your layout for sure, the migration is a pain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with: `npm install -S vuetify@2.0.1`

Answer (score 16):

As I cam across this question while having trouble with this, here is what I did:

```
npm install vuetify@latest
```

to update vuetify. Then change the initialisation of the vuetify object. It took a´while  to find the (actually obviously placed, but hard to google) [official guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/releases-and-migrations).

As I used the **plugin** architecture, i changed the files according to the first example:

```
// v2.0
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi',
  },
});

// src/main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Then I ran intro trouble with the sass-loader. To solve this, install sass, sass-loader and vuetify-loader as dev dependencies:

```
npm install --save-dev sass sass-loader@7 vuetify-loader
```

Note that I decided to force sass-loader in version 7, as I couldn't get version 8 to work, but I faintly remember seeing a note on what to do to make it work, but I couldn't find it again.

After this you can start migrating your code. I have to thank my helpful colleague for figuring out half of this for me.

Comment: Thanks for the bit about sass loader.  Did you ever find a way to make version 8 work?

Comment: @CamHart I haven't tried yet as I rather wanted to work on my app, sorry.