# Can't update Vuetify project to vuetify 2.0.0-beta5

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, webpack-encore

Got a problem when updating from `vuetify LTS` to `vuetify 2.0.0-beta.5`.

Before all worked great, vuetify styles were loading from app.scss

**Error:**

> [Vue warn]: Error in getter for watcher "isDark": "TypeError: Cannot
> read property 'dark' of undefined"
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'dark' of undefined
>
> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dark'
> of undefined"

I've uninstalled vuetify, then install and update it to a beta version like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49250912

**package.json**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.9.0",
    "@mdi/font": "^3.7.95",
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.22.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.8",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server --hot --disable-host-check --host 174.28.1.5 --public 174.28.1.5:8080",
    "dev": "encore dev",
    "watch": "encore dev --watch",
    "build": "encore production --progress"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apexcharts": "^3.8.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^3.1.4",
    "vue-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "vue-google-signin-button": "^1.0.4",
    "vue-telegram-login": "^2.1.0",
    "vuetify": "^1.5.14",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
var path = require('path');
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addStyleEntry('styles', './assets/css/app.scss')
    .enableSassLoader()
    .enableVueLoader()
    .addEntry('landing', './assets/js/modules/landing/main.js')
    .addEntry('main', './assets/js/modules/dashboard/main/main.js')
    .addEntry('main-m', './assets/js/modules/dashboard_m/main.js')
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
;
main_config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
main_config.resolve.alias["~"] = path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/js');
module.exports = main_config;
```

**main.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import store from './store/index'

Vue.component('current-session', () => import('./DashboardModule'));

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
    iconfont: 'fa'
});
Vue.use(VueApexCharts);

Vue.component('apexchart', VueApexCharts);

require('apexcharts');
require('vue-apexcharts');

new Vue({
    el: '#dashboard-m',
    store,
    components: {Dashboard},
    render: a => a(Dashboard),
});
```

**app.scss**

```
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
```

have made a try to fix it by adding vuetify-loader, not that i have made it correctly but it still not working, here my updates:

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin');
// .enableSassLoader() - turned off it
.addLoader({
    test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
    use: [
        'style-loader',
        'vue-style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
                implementation: require('sass'),
                fiber: require('fibers'),
                indentedSyntax: true, // optional
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

delete *node-sass from* **package.json**

So when a have added this

```html
<v-app id="inspire" :dark="false">
```

i have solved my problem with `<v-app>` tag, but got that **another components do not load default props**
like this:

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'register' of undefined"

or this:

> [Vue warn]: Error in getter for watcher "showOverlay": "TypeError:
> Cannot read property 'width' of undefined"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks **jacek** (Vuetify core team)
Here right way to add vuetify to Vue:

```
// v2.0
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

const opts = { ... }
Vue.use(Vuetify)

new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify(opts)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: thank you sir for this one. Saved me a lot of time. The next step is to load from vuetify/lib - it's broken in Vuetify beta 7.

Comment: to load what? css?

Comment: @Vixtrime, I guess the above method does not work in beta7. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57019082/4050261

Comment: @AdarshMadrecha, interesting, it still working for me after update to beta.7